# Why is my XMLHttpRequest response text null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am very new to Javascript and jQuery and I just got this piece of code which I need to try and fix. So I am trying to pull data from an external website which contains a string in JSON format. This contains an array {"data":[64759.148,44942.848712]} which I am trying to print out on my website. At first, I ran into an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error which I was able to fix. However, I am still unable to retrieve the data from this website. The console log shows NaN NaN, so there is an error in my get_live_data() function making my parsed response text null. What am I doing wrong?

```js
jQuery(function(){
    var counter1 = jQuery('#kwh-counter').jOdometer({ counterStart:'0000000000', numbersImage:'http://staging.five.my/glt/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/meter-num.png', heightNumber:25, spaceNumbers:1 });
    var counter2 = jQuery('#co2-counter').jOdometer({ counterStart:'0000000000', numbersImage:'http://staging.five.my/glt/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/meter-num.png', heightNumber:25, spaceNumbers:1 });
    
    function get_live_data(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "mywebsiteurl";
        var kwh = 0;
        var co2 = 0;
        
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                kwh = parseFloat(myArr[0]);
                co2 = parseFloat(myArr[1]);
                console.log(kwh, co2);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    counter1.goToNumber(Math.round(kwh));
    counter2.goToNumber(Math.round(co2));
    setTimeout(function(){ get_live_data(); }, 5000); // 5 seconds
        
    }
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var curr_pos = 0;
        var timer_id = 0; 

        function rotate_img(){ 
            if(curr_pos == -1833) curr_pos = 0;
            else curr_pos = curr_pos - 47;
            jQuery("#kwh-meter").css("background-position", "0px " + curr_pos + "px");
            if(curr_pos == -1833) curr_pos = 0;
        }
        function start_rotate(){
            timer_id = setInterval(rotate_img, 100);
        }
        function stop_rotate(){
            clearInterval(timer_id);
        }
        
        start_rotate();
        get_live_data();
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the value of  `myArr`?

Comment: @codemax Theoretically, myArr should be [64759.148,44942.848712].

Comment: But what is the actual value in `console.log`?

Comment: @codemax Oh... It's data: (2) [64762.79199999999, 44945.37764799999] But the data does change in real time. So how come myArr[0] is NaN?

Comment: You can only use `kwh` and `co2` inside the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` func.

Comment: Have you managed to try out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `kwh` and `co2` into the correct function scope.

```
    function get_live_data(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                kwh = parseFloat(myArr[0]);
                co2 = parseFloat(myArr[1]);
                console.log(kwh, co2);

                // move these 2 lines here
                counter1.goToNumber(Math.round(kwh));
                counter2.goToNumber(Math.round(co2));
            }
        };
    }
```